# Clarification on multiple MATCH and WHERE clauses

Tags: neo4j

I have question about the following statement from the Neo4j manual:

> In the case of multiple (OPTIONAL) MATCH clauses, the predicate in
>   WHERE is always a part of the patterns in the directly preceding
>   MATCH. Both results and performance may be impacted if the WHERE is
>   put inside the wrong MATCH clause.

Does this mean that I just need to be careful to keep to do:

```
MATCH clauseA WHERE predicateA
MATCH clauseB WHERE predicateB
```

rather than

```
MATCH clauseA, clauseB WHERE predicateA AND predicateB
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is what it means. And the same thing applies to OPTIONAL MATCH.